# Exponential map on Lie groups being a diffeomorphism

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Consider a Lie group $G$ and let it's Lie algebra be $\mathfrak{g}$. Let the exponential map be denoted by $\exp: \mathfrak{g} \to G$.

Given any $g \in G$, does there exist an open set $O \subset \mathfrak{g}$ with $g \in \exp(O)$ such that the exponential map restricted to $O$ is a diffeomorphism?

Note: I am not conversant with Riemannian geometry.

Comment: @amWhy No I am not acquainted with what the exponential map is in the context of Riemannian geometry. I wanted an explanation specific to Lie groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in general.

Let $G = S^3$, thought of as the unit length quaternions.  Let $g = -1$.  I claim that for any $x\in \exp^{-1}(g)$, and for any open neighborhood $O$ of $x$, that $\exp|_O:O\rightarrow G$ fails to be injective.  In particular, this restricted map cannot be a diffeomoprhism onto its image.

Note that $\mathfrak{g}$ can be identified with the imaginary quaternions (where the Lie bracket is the commutator).  If we declare the basis $\{i,j,k\}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ to be orthonormal, then the adjoint action of $G$ is isometric.  Also note that the adjoint action is simply the usual $SO(3)$ action on $\mathfrak{g}$ (a three dimensional vector space), so is transitive on any sphere centered at the origin.

Now, suppose $x\in \exp^{-1}(g)$.  Then, for any $h\in G$, we have $\exp(Ad_h x) = h\exp(x)h^{-1} = h(-1)h^{-1} = -1$, so $Ad_h x\in \exp^{-1}(g)$ as well.  Since the adjoint action is transitive on spheres, it follows that if $x\in \exp^{-1}(g)$, then all purely imaginary quaternions $y$ with $|x| = |y|$ are also in $\exp^{-1}(g)$.  In other words, $\exp^{-1}(g)$ consists of a union of spheres centered at the origin.

Restricting $x$ to be purely imaginary and complex, the group exponential is just the usual complex exponential map.  In particular, $\exp^{-1}(g)\cap \operatorname{Im}(\mathbb{C}) = \{ n\pi: n\text{is an odd integer}\}$.

Thus, $\exp^{-1}(g)$ consists of an infinite union of spheres centered at the origin, where there sphere each have radius an odd multiple of $\pi$.

Now, suppose $x\in \exp^{-1}(g)$ and let $O$ be any open neighborhood of $x$.  Since $x\in\exp^{-1}(g)$ it is one some sphere $S$ whose radious is an odd multiple of $\pi$.  But then $O\cap S$ is an infinite set.  In particular, for any $y\in O\cap S$, $\exp(y) = g$, so $\exp|_O$ is not injective.

Comment: Your answer is No but in linked post the answer is Yes!! What is the wrong?

Comment: @C.F.G:  I think the two questions being asked are different.  The linked one is about varying a point in the manifold from which you compute the exponential map.  The question I just answered has a fixed exponential map, but varies the point in the tangent space.  Of course, it's also quite possible that I made a mistake in my answer ;-)

Comment: May I ask what linked post you two are talking about? -- In the comments to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/301504/96384, David E Speyer brings up what to my understanding is essentially the same counterexample as this (+1).

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg:  It was https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833802/is-exponential-map-locally-a-diffeomorphism-w-r-t-base-point. And I agree that David Speyer's answer is essentially the same.  That said, I purposely avoided Riemannian geometry in my answer, since it wasn't clear the OP would be comfortable with it

Comment: Thank you for simplifying the example, I am indeed not conversant with Riemannian geometry.